# Application running over ssh (X11 forwarding) lagging a lot with local dual monitor

Tags: ssh, xorg, multiple-monitors, x11-forwarding, pycharm

I have 2 machines: 
- My Desktop (running ubuntu 15.04)
- Development machine (running ubuntu 14.04)
(both on same LAN)

So far, I've been working without any issues using "ssh -X eduardo@devel1" and them executing pycharm there.
Very fast, responsive and without any major issues.

If I connect a second display on my desktop, then everything changes. the toolbar menus (and any other popup like code autocomplete) is taking about 10 seconds to load! even if I run the application on the main display.

After some testing, I noticed that the problem is really related to the second display.

My displays:

- Built-in 1440x900
- hdmi (connected on thunderbolt port): 1920x1080

Any idea? 
I've tried to use ssh -Y instead, but the result was the same.

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, I've found an ugly workaround... switching off the display before launching the remote application and them turning it back on, solves the problem. Seems I've reading a bit and found an issue with java+x11-forwarding+dual monitor.
My workaround is lame but does the trick:
`xrandr --output HDMI1 --off ; ssh -X eduardo@devel1 "/home/eduardo/bin/pycharm/pycharm"`
for some reason the monitor automatically turns on after a few seconds, but it's enough to launch without the lag.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer while looking for a solution to the same problem. To be honest, I did not manage to entirely solve this issue, though I suspect it has something to do with the X11 protocol and I am sure there is proper fix for that out there. In the meantime, I found a workaround that makes it possible to run the application over SSH while keeping the other screen on.

Namely, need to run a **virtual machine on the local desktop** limited to a single screen and then connect via SSH to the remote server. It goes without saying that the virtual machine should have enough resources, especially video memory if the application is heavy on the visual aspect; network paravirtualization is also something nice to have.

This process can be a bit more of a hassle than simply turning off one display, but you get to use the two monitors in exchange. If you are going to run that application over SSH regularly, I find it's worthwhile setting the virtual machine - and most will probably have one already.

Comment: Could you expand on what it takes to do this? Are you suggesting running an additional virtual machine on the local desktop limited to one screen to connect to the remote system?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am suggesting, sorry if it was not entirely clear in my original message. It does not sound very elegant, I know, but to me it works better than the original solution proposed by the OP (as I need to use the other screen).